# Problem with Lucene- search not indexing numeric values?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

I am using Lucene in PHP (using the Zend Framework implementation).  I am having a problem that I cannot search on a field which contains a number.

Here is the data in the index:

```
      ts      |    contents
--------------+-----------------
  1236917100  | dog cat gerbil
  1236630752  |  cow pig goat
  1235680249  | lion tiger bear
  nonnumeric  | bass goby trout
```

**My problem**: A query for "`ts:1236630752`" returns no hits.  However, a query for "`ts:nonnumeric`" returns a hit.

I am storing "ts" as a keyword field, which [according to documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Search_Lucene/Document/Zend_Search_Lucene_Field.html#keyword) "is not tokenized, but is indexed and stored. Useful for non-text fields, e.g. date or url."  I have tried treating it as a "text" field, but the behavior is the same except that a query for "`ts:*`" returns nothing when ts is text.

I'm using Zend Framework 1.7 (just downloaded the latest 3 days ago) and PHP 5.2.9.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

//=========================================================
// Initializes Zend Framework (Zend_Loader).
//=========================================================
set_include_path(realpath('../library') . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();

//=========================================================
// Delete existing index and create a new one
//=========================================================
define('SEARCH_INDEX', 'test_search_index');
if(file_exists(SEARCH_INDEX))
  foreach(scandir(SEARCH_INDEX) as $file)
    if(!is_dir($file))
      unlink(SEARCH_INDEX . "/$file");

$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create(SEARCH_INDEX);

//=========================================================
// Create this data in index:
//         ts      |    contents
//   --------------+-----------------
//     1236917100  | dog cat gerbil
//     1236630752  |  cow pig goat
//     1235680249  | lion tiger bear
//     nonnumeric  | bass goby trout
//=========================================================

function add_to_index($index, $ts, $contents) {
  $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
  $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('ts', $ts));
  $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('contents', $contents));
  $index->addDocument($doc);
}

add_to_index($index, '1236917100', 'dog cat gerbil');
add_to_index($index, '1236630752', 'cow pig goat');
add_to_index($index, '1235680249', 'lion tiger bear');
add_to_index($index, 'nonnumeric', 'bass goby trout');

//=========================================================
// Run some test queries and output results
//=========================================================

echo '<html><body><pre>';

function run_query($index, $query) {
  echo "Running query:  $query\n";
  $hits = $index->find($query);
  echo 'Got ' . count($hits) . " hits.\n";
  foreach($hits as $hit)
    echo "  ts='$hit->ts', contents='$hit->contents'\n";
  echo "\n";
}

run_query($index, 'pig');           //1 hit
run_query($index, 'ts:1236630752'); //0 hits
run_query($index, '1236630752');    //0 hits
run_query($index, 'ts:pig');        //0 hits
run_query($index, 'contents:pig');  //1 hits
run_query($index, 'ts:[1236630700 TO 1236630800]'); //0 hits (range query)
run_query($index, 'ts:*');          //4 hits if ts is keyword, 1 hit otherwise
run_query($index, 'nonnumeric');    //1 hits
run_query($index, 'ts:nonnumeric'); //1 hits
run_query($index, 'trout');         //1 hits
```

**Output**

```
Running query:  pig
Got 1 hits.
  ts='1236630752', contents='cow pig goat'

Running query:  ts:1236630752
Got 0 hits.

Running query:  1236630752
Got 0 hits.

Running query:  ts:pig
Got 0 hits.

Running query:  contents:pig
Got 1 hits.
  ts='1236630752', contents='cow pig goat'

Running query:  ts:[1236630700 TO 1236630800]
Got 0 hits.

Running query:  ts:*
Got 4 hits.
  ts='1236917100', contents='dog cat gerbil'
  ts='1236630752', contents='cow pig goat'
  ts='1235680249', contents='lion tiger bear'
  ts='nonnumeric', contents='bass goby trout'

Running query:  nonnumeric
Got 1 hits.
  ts='nonnumeric', contents='bass goby trout'

Running query:  ts:nonnumeric
Got 1 hits.
  ts='nonnumeric', contents='bass goby trout'

Running query:  trout
Got 1 hits.
  ts='nonnumeric', contents='bass goby trout'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The find() method tokenizes the query, and with the default Analzer your numbers will be pretty much ignored.  If you want to search for a number you have to [construct the query](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html) or use an alternate [analyzer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.extending.html#zend.search.lucene.extending.analysis) that includes numeric values..

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.searching.html

> It is important to note that the
>   query parser uses the standard
>   analyzer to tokenize separate parts of
>   query string. Thus all transformations
>   which are applied to indexed text are
>   also applied to query strings.
>
> The standard analyzer may transform
>   the query string to lower case for
>   case-insensitivity, remove stop-words,
>   and stem among other transformations.
>
> The API method doesn't transform or
>   filter input terms in any way. It's
>   therefore more suitable for computer
>   generated or untokenized fields.

Comment: Note that newer versions of Zend Search Lucene include an alphanumeric analyzer; you just have to set it as default.  Make sure to include this near the beginning of your indexing script as well as before you run $index->find():

    Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive());

Answer (score 2):

I'm used to using Lucene under Java so I can't tell if your code is correct but it seems like the field is being tokanized in a manner that is stripping out anything exept [a-zA-Z].

It may help shed light on the situation to use an index explorer tool like http://www.getopt.org/luke/ to see exactly what is in the index.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get text and numbers pretty readily by using Zend/Search/Lucene/Analysis/Analyzer/Common/TextNum.php as the default (use ::setDefault(...) as described above.

My problem is that I was trying to index a large set of software and hardware wtih a long history and many version numbers. Zend Search Lucene was not tokenizing "words" like "1.5.3" or anything with a dot (IP addresses, e.g.), underscore or hyphen.

I first made a copy of TextNum.php, renamed TextNumSSC.php (SSC is our application name) and tried editing the RegEx:

```
do {
                 if (! preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+/', $this->_input, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $this->_position)) { 
                     // It covers both cases a) there are no matches (preg_match(...) === 0)
                     // b) error occured (preg_match(...) === FALSE)
                     return null;
                 }
```

Still no luck.

Then I installed http://codefury.net/projects/StandardAnalyzer/ in the way instructed, outside the Zend directory structure, changed the RegEx to

```
'/[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+/'
```

and now it works.

Not sure the root cause of this, but couldn't find anything on SO or web to address this dot issue.